# Is there a way to have PHP objects to "act" like native types?

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implicit Type Conversion for PHP Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066003/implicit-type-conversion-for-php-classes)

Let's say I want to define my own native types, or just looking to bridge an Object to a native type.

For example, take this class:

```
class Integer {

 private $num;
  function __construct($number){
   $this->num = $number;
  }

}
```

Is there a way I can use this class doing:

```
$n = new Integer(14);
echo $n+3; //output 17
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, just using a similar example.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't look like a dupe.

Comment: Why __toString isn't working in this case? (tested)

Comment: @fabrik: __toString works only with strings, so $n."3" will work

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading)? It's not supported in PHP.

Comment: Would be great if PHP had such feature... Not only for `echo $n + 3`, but also for things like `$n += 3`.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest another solution for 5.3. You can implement [__invoke()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) method and write like this:

```
$n = new Integer(14);
echo $n()+3; //output 17
```

The full code:

```
<?php
class Integer {

 private $num;
  function __construct($number){
   $this->num = $number;
  }
  public function __invoke() {
    return $this->num;
  }
}

$n = new Integer(14);
echo $n() + 3; //output 17
```

Comment: You want __invoke to know which type it must return, right? And it comes down to func_get_args, switch, and just not clean code. I think $n->toInteger() is more obvious and clean than for example $n('integer').

Comment: Well, if the class is named Integer() it seems obvious, that __invoke() should return just integer. Anyway, this approach (implicit type conversion for objects) no matter how it is emulated should not be used in production code because this implementation is alien to PHP. All we show here are just examples of how such functionality can theoretically be emulated most closely.

Comment: Just to add: I never told anything about $n('integer') because this will be overcomplicating matter to me. __invoke in my example should be used only on classes which are obvious to be cast to certain type only. Not to many different types if you use such functionality at all.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support implicit conversion on custom types or classes, so such constructs won't work. I think the easiest (though boring) way is to implement your own methods in such objects like `toInteger`, `toString`, `toBoolean`, etc. and always call them when you want to perform basic operations.

Like this:

```
$n = new Integer(14);
echo $n->toInteger() + 3; //output 17
```

Comment: `toString()` can be implemented with magic method `__toString()`, which is used to convert object to string when object is used in string context (e.g., `$object . 'string'` or `(string)$object`).

Comment: Yes, I know. But there is a word: consistency. Either name methods __toInteger, __toBoolean, __toString or toInteger, toBoolean, and toString. That's bad PHP has only the magic method for strings. That is if you in one case rely on one magic method and don't call it explicitly, and in other cases on your own methods, you're doing it wrong. (That's my opinion.)

Comment: Thank, but I was looking for a native PHP implementation.

Comment: There's no point in calling `toInteger()` as `__toInteger()`. And there is no point in using `__toString()` as `$string = $object->__toString()`. What I would do would be implementing `__toString()` and then using it in `toString()`, i.e., `public function toString() { return (string)$this; }` - that way you get both consistency in naming methods (`toString`, `toInt` etc) AND you still can use `__toString()` as it is meant to be used in PHP.

Comment: There's no native implementation for implicit type conversion in PHP.

Comment: Thanks stam, it was worth a try just to check that I didn't miss it.

Comment: @binaryLV You're correct with `public function toString() { return (string)$this; }` I would implement it this way, too. I wasn't trying to say that you don't have to implement `__toString` :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
class Integer{
    private $Integer;
    function __construct($n){
        $this->Integer = (int)$n;    
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->Integer);
    }
}

$n = new Integer(14);
$a = strval($n);
echo $a+3; //Ouptups 17
```

Comment: Well, why strval is better here than $n->value() then?